# Static image assets in rails app not displaying on Heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

I tried pre-compiling my images before deployment using the command:

`$ RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile`

I am using `image_tag`'s in my templates that work in development.

Update: `config.serve_static_files` is said to default to true in dev, but then is turned off in production because the assets should be provided via your web server. I currently am just using the free tier on heroku and am still running webrick, so I have this set to true, but no luck.

Update 2: When I set `config.serve_static_files` to `false`, heroku does not see any of my assets, all my stylings go away and images remain unfound. Although heroku does send a warning message upon pushing to master saying that all "`config.serve_static_files` does is enables serving everything in the public folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline.". I suppose it is unrelated to the asset pipeline in that it is just serving up the assets in the public folder and does not look at our assets directory. I also see that heroku runs the precompile command upon deployment, so I don't need to do that each time.

This makes me wonder if the way I am calling my assets using the `image_tag` could be the problem, but I am not sure why that would be?

Update 3: The rails guide for the asset pipeline says "In regular views you can access images in the public/assets/images directory like this: `<%= image_tag "rails.png" %>`. I am calling for my image using this convention like so `<%= image_tag("lab49", size: "80x30") %>`, but the image will still not appear.

Update 4: See my answer.

Comment: In case it's useful, I had the same problem on fly.io (i.e. a platform other than heroku). So I think the issue is to do with dev vs production (rather than being specific to heroku).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you came to this post and you are using Heroku, Heroku will accept your images only if you use the image file extension.

This will work:

```
<%= image_tag "lab49.png", size: "80x30" %>
```

This will not work (although it will locally):

```
<%= image_tag "lab49", size: "80x30" %>
```

Comment: You sir are a hero!

Comment: Confirmed this resolved the issue for me on 5.1.3. 

Thanks bro!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

Something to watch out for: 
I had jpeg files in my assets/images folder. When I ran rake assets:precompile they were turned into .jpg files. After renaming them in my assets/images folder to .jpg, precompiling, and pushing again they displayed on Heroku just fine.

Comment: Same was happening to [many others](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/304#issuecomment-531256875)