# In Rails 4+ app, I have deployed App to heroku but static Images are not loading in production but working in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I have Tried every answer for last two days but nothing worked for me. Problem is my static images doesn't get loaded in production but work fines in Development. I have even `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`. This works and  precompile my assets. I see static images in Public/Assets folder.

## Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
gem 'searchkick'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'tinymce-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.8'
gem 'haml'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.6'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", "~> 0.2.1"
gem 'acts_as_votable'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.66.0'
gem 'foreman'
gem 'puma'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'
gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 0.10.1'
gem 'execjs', '~> 2.7'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

## production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)

end
```

One more interesting thing i found was even though my static images are in `public/assets`,image tag have src link like `images/abc.jpg`, Not pointing to public assets images

## Code

```
<%= link_to root_path,class:"navbar-brand" do %>
    <h1><%= image_tag("logo",alt:"Bitnotes") %></h1>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you add your code for the image tag? Maybe the problem lies there..

Comment: Check the code for Image Tag

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320418/static-image-assets-in-rails-app-not-displaying-on-heroku-production

Comment: Doesn't work @prasad.surase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Trying 4 Days, Here is Solution to above Problem

```
gem 'tinymce-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.8'
```

gem doesn't let assets to precompile. So I removed the above gem and removed

```
//= require tinymce
//= require tinymce-jquery
```

from the `application.js`

Then made this `config.assets.compile = true` change in production.rb.

Finally Precompiled assets with

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

committed all the changes and pushed to heroku with

`git push heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding this `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` to your Gemfile and deploy to Heroku again. And you don't need to set `config.serve_static_files` in your `production.rb` file.

Comment: It doesn't work, Problem is In production image path is not pointing to `public/assets` folder. It is showing `assets/images/filename`

Comment: @ChaitanyaYadav where do you place images?

Comment: `app/assets/images`